# Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported when trying npm run storybook

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, storybook

when i try `npm run storybook`

I am getting following error in terminal

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
```

OS - Mac Pro M1

my story book script as follows

```
"storybook" : "start-storybook -p 6006 -s public"
```

react application staring without any issues, but story book not working

Normally this type of issue i am solving with

```
--openssl-legacy-provider
```

but when i try this solution for above case

```
error: unknown option '--openssl-legacy-provider'
```

getting this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to install `"webpack": "^5.75.0"` as development dependency. After installing webpack storybook working fine